# For which $n$ does $\sqrt{n }< n/2$ hold?

Tags: square-numbers, integers

When testing with some positive values except for $1$, it seems that $\sqrt{n} \leq n/2$.
However I did not see that property anywhere. Is it true ? Would it be possible to prove it ?

Thanks.

Ps: it is for computing the integer square root of a number. You can use binary search between $[0,\ldots, n]$ (and reducing the set of candidate to a 1 entry array). But if $n > 1$ AND if this property holds, you could use it between $[0,\ldots, n/2]$ which could lead to higher performance !

Comment: Try plotting $y=\sqrt{x}$ and $y=x/2$ on the same graph.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Multiply by two, and square (which is alright in this case) to get the equivalent

$$4n \le n^2$$

Now cancel $n$ (which is also alright in this case) to get $4\le n$.

The inequality (in the body) is true if and only if $n \ge 4$, the one in the title if this inequality is strict.

Comment: Eheh. I should have squeezed my brain a little more -_-" Perfect ! Thank you ! (will accept in 9 mn as required ...)

Comment: Why it's alright in this case? As long as you don't say that complex numbers don't satisfy the requirements of ordered field, therefore this inequality has no sense (in complex domain — so, we permit only real numbers) and for $n<0, \sqrt{n}$ doesn't exist, this answer isn't complete. (We had to assume, that $n\geq0$, so two sides are non-negative and we can square both sides.)

Comment: The question states (or at least implies) that it is intended for positive integers. As you can see I said "in this case" both times, by which I mean for the context of this question, which I took to be positive integers.

Comment: Exactly. I did not say that explicitly (I should have then ;) but with the "n" variable which is often used as an Integer , and the "integer" tag, you could have guessed !

Answer (score 2):

For $n>0$,
$$\sqrt n<\frac n2\iff n<\frac{n^2}4\iff n(n-4)>0\iff n>4$$